# Android Cannot anchor FAB button to BottomSheet

Tags: android, button, floating-action-button

I'm trying to attach a FAB button to the BottomSheet view like Google Maps does. However I cannot make it work,

this is the code of the FAB button:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/nestedscrollview" --> BottomSheet view ID
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    />
```

and this is the code of the BottomSheet View

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
tools:context="com.pub.uac.ui.location.LocationActivity"
android:background="@color/background_white_trasnparent"
 > 
... 
</...
```

Comment: try this example on github..............https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: I am also trying the same thing did you get it resolved?

Comment: not yet, still trying to find out how to hook the ID

Comment: I have posted a question here lets see what happens...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985403/botomsheetdialog-fabbutton-anchor-view-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what you mean by "cannot make it work" and also what you try to achieve.

Does it work better if you set on the FAB:

```
  app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
```

You used "bottom" instead of "top", so the FAB will not be pushed by the bottom sheet, it will stay at the bottom. With "top" it should at least follow the sheet.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. But my FAB is now half obscured by my bottom sheet. Is there another setting for `layout_anchorGravity` I can use such that the **bottom** of my anchored view is on **top** of my bottom sheet?

Comment: You need to set the `elevetion` of both the bottom sheet and your FAB so that the FAB has a higher elevation

Comment: And it seems that you need to use the `app` namespace when you do that