# Android set anchor to Bottom Sheets

Tags: android, anchor, bottom-sheet

I wanna set an anchor to my Bottom Sheet:

```
<!-- bottom sheets -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bottom sheets test! " />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! bottom sheets content! " />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

I add the FAB as the direct child of the CoordinateLayout and set the bottom sheet's id to the FAB's layout_anchor and set its layout_anchorGravity. But it doesn't work.The FAB won't move.

Comment: did you implemented java code also?

Comment: @sasikumar my bottom sheets works fine but the anchor doesn't work. Does anchor need some java code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced same problem and I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37068484/4142087

It will work, if you will change your code to this:

```
app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
```

Comment: Thx.It works.But I find that when I drag the anchor, the bottomsheet doesn't move.When i drag the bottom sheet, it works well.Do I miss something?

Comment: @AllenVork looks like no, it works as expected. Only bottom sheet is draggable here, anchor point means only that view will follow another view it's anchored to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="end" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It just change the position of the FAB.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Just make sure it's within a Coordinator Layout.

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />
```